# Reset Factory Iterator in Factoryboy

Tags: python, factory-boy

Since the factory assigns the value to the factory attribute it's not possible to call reset on it.

This however works:

```
CODE2_ITERATOR = Iterator(['PH', 'CN', 'SE', 'ES', 'DK' ])

class CountryFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
    model = Country

    name = 'The Philippines'
    code2 = CODE2_ITERATOR
    phone = "63"
```

Then in your `tearDown` method:

```
def tearDown(self):
    CODE2_ITERATOR.reset()
```

But surely there must be a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field declaration stays available through the class:

```
CountryFactory.code2.reset()
```

You can also access the declaration objects of a factory through the class' `_meta` attribute:

```
CountryFactory._meta.declarations['code2'].reset()
```